# 3 Shipping options in shipping method magento

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping-methods

I am working on site .where now i want to show 3 options for the shipping method like 1) UK base (2) Europ Base (3) Rest world.I try to add direct code to collectRates function of Carrier model but didn't succeded.Can anyone guide me how can i do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tablerates` shipping method to have a shipping option depending on the shipping address country. If someone already selected France as shipping country it might be a bit of overkill to ask them if they want the Europe Base option since that's where they want it send.

Comment: I agree with you ,but i have to implement the way as i ask.